# How can I change this kick command fully to get a reply when you try to kick a member that is not in the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have this kick command I have coded and it is working perfectly fine. My question is, how can I change the command so that I get a reply saying as an example "You can't kick this user since they are not in this server" or so.

Here is my code:

```js
const { Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "Kick a member",
    userPermission: ["KICK_MEMBERS"],
    options: [
        {
            name: "target",
            description: "target to kick",
            type: "USER",
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: "reason",
            description: "reason for this kick",
            type: "STRING",
            required: false,
        }
    ],
    /**
     * 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     * @param {String} args 
     */
    execute: async(interaction, client, args) => {
        const { options, member, guild } = interaction;

        const target = options.getMember("target");
        const reason = options.getString("reason") || "No reason provided";

        if(!target.roles.highest.position >= member.roles.highest.position) return interaction.reply({content: "You can't take action on this user as their role is higher than yours!",
    });

    await target.send({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("AQUA").setTitle(" Kicked").setAuthor(target.user.tag, target.user.avatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 512})).setDescription(`You have been kicked from **${guild.name}**!\nReason: \`${reason}\``).setFooter(`ID: ${target.user.id}`)]});

    target.kick(reason);

    interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("GREEN").setTitle(" Kick").setAuthor(target.user.tag, target.user.avatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 512})).setDescription(`**${target.user.tag}** has successfully been kicked from **${guild.name}**!\n**Reason:** \`${reason}\``).setFooter(`ID: ${target.user.id}`)]});
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a slash command and requires a `USER` here:

```js
name: "target",
description: "target to kick",
type: "USER",
required: true
```

Then there can never exist a possibility of this command running without the user being in the guild. The command would error before it was sent.

Edit:

Also your line

```js
const target = options.getMember("target");
```

Should be

```js
const target = options.getUser("target");
```

You would need to get the `member` using the below:

```js
const targetMember = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === target)
```

Then every line below that where `target` is used change to `targetMember`

Edit answering question in comments:

To kick/ban someone not in the guild

```js
const targetMember = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === target)

if (targetMember = undefined) {
// code to kick/ban
} else {
// normal code
}
```

Comment: So you're saying it is not possible that the bot gives you a reply saying that this user is not in the server when you try to kick someone that isn't in the server?

Comment: When the command is run, it pops up with a list of all members when you get to that option, if you try to type in someone who isn’t there list is empty. If you try to continue anyways then the command changes to this (from my discord as example) and will not even let you send it. https://ibb.co/DDWPdDq

Comment: And the bot notifies the person trying use the command. See that with this example without using the reason option. https://ibb.co/kHJwY00

Comment: And how is it for the ban comment? Example when you ban you can include an ID, and what happens when you try to ban someone using their ID who isn't in the server? <-- cuz this then gives an error in the logs

Comment: So this is what I have found, you can use the built in kick/ban commands and input a ID number and it will "kick" (but not actually kick the user cause they really arent there), however the built in ban command will work if the user is not a member

I would assume there is a way to make it work (in case you need to ban someone that has already left the guild). I tested on my bot and just using the ID or even wrapping the id in <@id> didn't work. More research on how to get a user when they aren't in the guild may be needed. Discord bot Clyde can do it because Clyde is in all guilds

Comment: Found out why my bot wouldn't process a kick or ban when the member wasn't in the guild, my bot checks the permissions of the person being kicked/banned before it runs. So if you were to put an if statement to work around that it could work. I updated answer to help with that

Comment: And that still wont work, I tested in many ways the `client.users.fetch(id)` will not escape above the current guild(s) that it is in